# Stroke in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How to Stroke a line in Cocos2d? Is it possible to convert the stroke into sprite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw lines by overriding the "draw" method, which would in turn result in the "stroke" effect you appear to be after.  The question is a bit lacking in detail, so I'll try to make the best of it.

Let's say you want to draw a simple line on the screen, you could do the following:

```
@interface MyLine: CCNode
{
  CGRect lineRect;
}
@property(nonatomic) CGRect lineRect;
+(id)lineWithRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end

@implementation MyLine
@synthesize lineRect
+(id)lineWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  MyLine *node = [MyLine node];
  [node setRect: rect];
  return node];
}
-(void)draw
{
  glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
  ccDrawLine(ccp(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y), ccp(rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
}
@end
```

With this class, you'd be able to call:

```
MyLine *line = [MyLine lineWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.width, winSize.height)];
```

Which would then draw a line from the bottom left of the screen to the top right of the screen.

You would not convert this into a "sprite", as it would be unnecessary to do so - but you could then treat this as if it were any other graphic in your game, as it is now it's own subclass of CCNode ... containing all the goodness that comes with that (positioning, etc).